# How can i find the end of a html document which is displayed in android webview

Tags: android, html, webview

I'm displaying webpages using webview, these webpages are stored in sqlite file and each row of sqlite table contains a  html page.
I need to fetch next html page when user comes end of running html page.
 My question is how can trigger a notification to code when scrolling ends in a webview(means end of html page)? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a java script function which will tell you that you have the reached at the end of your HTML document and this same java script function will communicate with your android(JAVA) code to load next page OR do whatever you want.

please follow this [article](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript) for learning "how to communicate between android and JS code."

Comment: sorry. you have to find this urself. You can start searching on google!!